# c# SplashScreen Assembly Loaded does work

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, splash-screen

I want to show my application assembly loaded first when starting
application.

After application starts running, my code does not show anything.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new    
    AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);
}


void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Loaded " + args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
   label1.Text = "Loaded " + args.LoadedAssembly.FullName;

   Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Its possible that by the time you've added your event handler the code is already loaded, or, that you havent loaded your code yet...

Comment: For one thing, I don't think it's safe to assume you can access UI controls within that event handler. Beyond that, it's unclear what you're expecting here - the code you've shown is too little to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call it in your `Main();` When the form is showing up, all assemblies are loaded, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx